# Spring Social LinkedIn: Is there an api available to retrieve user's projects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-social-linkedin

I am currently using Spring Social LinkedIn 1.0.0.Release to log users into my site.  I have a feature where I need access to the user's projects.  At this time, I don't see a way to get access to the their projects.  I reviewed the Spring Social LinkedIn code and found no impl of retrieving this data.  I was able to build a rest endpoint to get access and build a crude mapper to return an Java object.  I am waiting for a proper implementation by the Spring Social LinkedIn community.  I thought I would check to see if there are any plans to build an api to get user's projects.  The rest url to get projects is below:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(projects:(id,name,description,occupation,start-date,end-date,members)

Thanks,

Sajid

Answer (score 2):

The URL to get Project URL and other info of Linkedin User :-

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(projects:(id,name,description,occupation,start-date,end-date,members),honors-awards,related-profile-views,job-bookmarks,three-past-positions,three-current-positions,industry,associations,interests,formatted-phonetic-name,formatted-name,id,num-connections,picture-url,skills,educations,date-of-birth,languages,email-address,headline,summary,specialties,location,public-profile-url,positions)?format=json

Comment: This API no longer works. Is there any alternative to get and set the user's Projects in Profile? Thanks.

Comment: This API is working. In case you are not getting a respective result then just try to test API URI on https://apigee.com/console/linkedin. This site provides a facilities to test different social API. Just do login and copy and paste API URL and run.